# How to I test SSL Authentication in Haproxy using cURL or Postman?

Tags: ssl, curl, postman, haproxy

I have an Haproxy server with the following configurations.

```
frontend my-front-end
  bind *:8443 accept-proxy ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/acme.dev.test.pem  ca-file /etc/haproxy/certs/ca.pem verify required
  http-request set-header X-SSL                       %[ssl_fc]
  http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Verify         %[ssl_c_verify]
  http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-SHA1           %{+Q}[ssl_c_sha1]
  http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-DN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn]
  http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-CN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
  http-request set-header X-SSL-Issuer                %{+Q}[ssl_c_i_dn]
  acl validcert ssl_c_s_dn(cn) -m reg ^(acme-acme-API-TEST-Signing)$
  http-request deny if !validcert
  ...
```

How do I use cURL or Postman to make a GET https request that satisfies the SSL verification?
I tried "--cert acmeroot.pem" but got

```
curl: (35) error:1401E410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: are you using SSL v3.0?

Comment: using "openssl s_client -connect acme.host.com:6443 -nbio_test" it uses TLS1.2.